# " 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged" error when trying to remove a file from github history

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I've uploaded a file to github. After running git rm  and pushing (which deleted the fole from the repository) I tried:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <file_to_remove>'  HEAD
```

and it deleted the file contents from each commit on the commits section. However, the file contents still apear in a commit within some issue, having a commit id that doesn't appear in the commit section.

After deleting the .git/refs/original and trying that command once again even with -f it gave me a warning
that 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged and the git status shows nothing changed..

please help me

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Answer (score 3):

This means that the new `HEAD`, transformed by your filter, had the same commit id as the original `HEAD` and therefore the command has had no effect.  The name `refs/heads/master` is the full name for the branch that your `HEAD` was on.

What is difficult is working out why nothing changed.  I just encountered this  with `--filter-branch` where my sed pattern was subtly wrong so it never matched anything.

Similarly for your `git rm` it never found the `<file_to_remove>`.  Perhaps you didn't specify the full path or just had a typo.  (Shell expansion of wildcards could also be a [problem](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#_examples) but your use of single quotes should prevent that.)